# Mais si tu ne vas pas à Lagardère, Lagardère ira à toi

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

> *Mais si tu ne vas pas à Lagardère, Lagardère ira à toi.*

Peut-on utiliser de nos jours la phrase ci-dessus, voulant dire :

> Si sa volonté ne prévaut pas, il faut se soumettre à une alternative.

Toujours dans le même contexte, en anglais (et en grec aussi:-)!) on peut dire :

> *If the mountain will not come to Muhammad (...then Muhammad must go to the mountain).*

Voir ici : https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-the-mountain-will-not-come-to-muhammad.html

En français, peut-on utiliser cette expression comme il l'a déjà été fait par un certain Jean le Rond d'Alembert :

https://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/citations/citation-36653.php

Comment: J'ai une interprétation différente de la phrase titre _Mais si tu ne vas pas à Lagardère, Lagardère ira à toi_: je comprends que toute tentative d'échapper à son destin est inutile. Lagardère te retrouvera un jour ou l'autre même si tu le fuis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Cette possibilité ne convient pas, sa construction n'est conforme à aucune de celles utilisées pour un adage. Les deux phrases ci-dessous conviennent mais il pourrait y en avoir d'autres.

- (*possibilité 1*) Qui ne peut pas faire prévaloir sa volonté  doit se soumettre à une alternative.
- (*possibilité 2*) Si on ne peut pas faire prévaloir sa volonté il faut se soumettre à une alternative.

**2.** Certainement, les citations sont toujours réutilisables, et sans remarques ajoutées quant à leur auteur lorsqu'elles sont très connues. Cependant, lorsqu'il s'agit de citations peu connues, que l'auteur soit quelqu'un de l'entourage ou non, il est recommandé de lui attribuer la citation (note en pied de page ou remarque dans la phrase (comme le dit untel, selon la façon de voir de untel,…) ; ne pas le faire risque de faire penser au lecteur qui ne connait pas la citation que l'on en est l'auteur.

Par exemple si dans une équipe de travail tous les employés connaissent un phrase lapidaire de l'un de leurs collègues, alors une personne sachant cela peut se passer de mentionner son auteur dans une lettre à l'un d'eux ; mais si cette phrase n'a été énoncée qu'en présence de la personne qui écrit et que celle-ci ne sait pas si la phrase est connue ou non des autres, elle a tout intérêt a reconnaitre son auteur.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a un proverbe courant qui peut être plus adapté (et plus facilement reconnaissable):

> Faute de grives, on mange des merles

qui signifie que faute d'avoir ce qu'on souhaite, il faut se contenter d'une alternative moins enthousiasmante.

On peut dire simplement *Faute de grives...* sans finir la phrase, et l'interlocuteur en comprend alors le sens.